# How to show IntelliJ JSON editor in dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, intellij-idea-2016

I want to show below kind of an editor inside a dialog in an plugin that I'm developing for Kotlin and Java. I tried the below code snippet

```
    editorTextField.setEnabled(true);
    editorTextField.setOneLineMode(false);
    editorTextField.setFileType(new JsonFileType());
```

Could someone point out how to achieve this?

Particularly I need the line numbers, JSON syntax highlighting and code folding I can see all the code specifications [here](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/idea-ce/structure/idea-ce-d00d8b4ae3ed33097972b8a4286b336bf4ffcfab/json/src/com/intellij/json). Please help me in learning how can I use them in my plugins.

JSON editor :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
class JsonOutputDialog(language: Language, project: Project, text: String) : DialogWrapper(project) {

    private val panel = JPanel(BorderLayout())

    init {
        super.setOKActionEnabled(false)

        init()

        val editorTextField = CustomEditorField(language, project, text)
        editorTextField.setOneLineMode(false)
        editorTextField.preferredSize = Dimension(800, 600)

        editorTextField.isVisible = true

        panel.add(editorTextField)

        editorTextField.setCaretPosition(0)
    }

    override fun createCenterPanel() = panel
}

class CustomEditorField(language: Language, project: Project, s: String) : LanguageTextField(language, project, s) {

    override fun createEditor(): EditorEx {
        val editor = super.createEditor()
        editor.setVerticalScrollbarVisible(true)
        editor.setHorizontalScrollbarVisible(true)

        val settings = editor.settings
        settings.isLineNumbersShown = true
        settings.isAutoCodeFoldingEnabled = true
        settings.isFoldingOutlineShown = true
        settings.isAllowSingleLogicalLineFolding = true
        settings.isRightMarginShown=true
        return editor
    }
}
```

This is what you need to do. The key here is to use `LanguageTextField` instead of `EditorTextField` and override the `createEditor()` method to configure all the options that you are looking for like Line Numbers and Code Folding.